# Build GDB for ESP32 and QEMU

Tags: gdb, qemu, esp32

I tried to build a gdb for esp32 that works with qemu, but after many attempt, I didn't manage. All my attempts leaded me to the following error message after connecting to the remote target: `Remote 'g' packet reply is too long`.

Right now I am using the prebuilt version from Ebiroll: https://github.com/Ebiroll/qemu_esp32/blob/master/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gdb
but I would like to use a newer gdb version than 7.10, did anyone had success with this?

Here is how I built gdb:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch esp-2021r2-gdb https://github.com/espressif/binutils-gdb.git
cd binutils-gdb
mkdir -p build
cd build
../configure --without-guile --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=xtensa-esp32-elf --disable-werror
make
make install
```

(note from this branch the patch to apply from the Zephyr project, as described here https://github.com/Ebiroll/qemu_esp32#qemu-esp32, seems to already be included)

I also tried by applying the following patch (no success):

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ebiroll/gdb/master/gdb/xtensa-config.c.qemu --output binutils-gdb/gdb/xtensa-config.c
```

or patching qemu to fix the value of num_regs (tried 104 and 172, also no success).

Answer (score 2):

Espressif's [qemu wiki](https://github.com/espressif/qemu/wiki#gdb-compatibility-for-esp-2021r1-and-earlier-toolchain-releases) mentions setting an environment variable to only list the core registers:

```
export QEMU_XTENSA_CORE_REGS_ONLY=1
```

This needs to be set in the environment from where qemu will be executed.

My recommendation is to use both qemu and gdb (from the [Esp32 tool chain](https://github.com/espressif/crosstool-NG/releases)) as provided by Espressif. I have recently used this combination with success. The latest release uses gdb 9.2.

Comment: An up-to-date toolchain (esp-2021r2 and later) doesn't need this environment variable, it just works.

Comment: It might also be needed to pass `--mcpu=esp32` to Espressif's fork of GDB